# Player gravity turns off while i move in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am quite new to unity and I have two scripts, one for gravity and one for player movement as the names suggest. The reason I am using a gravity script is that the third person movement doesn't support using a rigidbody with position and rotation enabled, so I have frozen the position and the rotation inside the rigidbody (which turns off gravity in the rigidbody). I made the Gravity script myself but I followed a tutorial on the player movement script because I have no idea how to make third person movement so I don't really know what is going on in the movement script.

Movement script:

```
public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        UnityEngine.Vector3 direction = new UnityEngine.Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);

            transform.rotation = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            UnityEngine.Vector3 moveDir = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * UnityEngine.Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

    }
}
```

Gravity script:

```
public class gravityScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float GravitySpeed = -0.03f;
    public bool GravityCheck = false;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Terrain0_0")
        {
            GravityCheck = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        GravityCheck = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (GravityCheck == false)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, GravitySpeed, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Add in a Debug.Log into the OnCollisionEnter and the OnCollisionExit and try to see when these events are being fired and if they are being fired. I would also recommend renaming GravityCheck to applyGravity and making the if statement `if (applyGravity == true)`. The term GravityCheck and what it meant threw me off a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened but when I opened it today (the day after posting) it was working fine. It was likely just a bug that got fixed after a restart.